# Run MochaJS tests on Heroku NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, mocha.js, foreman

I have an extensive MochaJS test suite for my ExpressJS / NodeJS API. The test suite includes creation of objects and removal of those same objects from the database.

Currently, all of my regression tests are passing in my development environment. We'd like to be able to run the same test on the staging environment that has data objects that were migrated and not created after the new code was deployed.

How do we run our mocha tests from the server?

Currently, I use the following command to run my tests, locally:

```
foreman run node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team decided to go the route of using continuous integration as the mechanism for running server side tests. Two birds with one stone!

We're using CircleCI to make that happen.

We're now passing the supertest library the app module rather than a URL. This allows the endpoints to be called at the HTTP layer by supertest.

Hope this helps anyone else looking at similar alternatives!

Answer (score 2):

You can probably leverage the package.json **scripts**:

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

If heroku uses a simple `npm install` to install your package, you can define a `prepublish` script which runs mocha. It's as simple as defining this in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "mocha"
}
```

Don't worry about `mocha` not being installed globally, `npm install` will add the `node_modules/.bin` folder to the `PATH` environment variable during installation.